# Outlook 365 replacing commas with underscores in subject line

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I click and drag an email from my inbox and move it into a desktop folder, the commas and periods in the subject lines turn into underscores. Is this a feature in outlook that can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

It replaces commas and periods with underscores because not all file systems gracefully handle commas and periods in names of files. Letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores are widely viewed as safe. Spaces are slightly less safe, but they aren't much of an issue these days. Then come the other symbols. Outlook decides to play it safe and replaces at least some special characters with an underscore.

And even if the file system allows a certain character, you can't always predict what will be done with that file later on. You might want to zip it up, or burn it to DVD, or write it to a backup tape, or upload it to an SFTP site, or send it to someone who uses a different file system. In any of those cases, you might run in to a situation that doesn't like a special character that your file system was fine with. So Outlook is just trying to take a conservative approach.

> Is this a feature in outlook that can be changed?

I can't find a way to change it. A [Microsoft Community discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/how-can-i-save-an-outlook-message-with-the-sender/b1933b90-cc71-4b77-a623-9c78909917a2) suggests using a macro to handle the saving, in which case you can decide exactly how to change (or not change) characters, but I don't know if it will work for you in Outlook 365.

(Gmail does the same thing with slashes, colons and double quotes, but not with commas, periods, apostrophes, exclamation marks, and percent signs.)